# FATAL: While performing build: conveyor failed to get: while converting reference: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io:

Tags: dockerhub, singularity-container, apptainer

I install apptainer by following the instructions from https://github.com/apptainer/apptainer/issues/url. After fresh installation "apptainer build" command gives error while building from .def file

```
apptainer build --fakeroot container/fastqc.sif container/fastqc.def
INFO: Starting build...
FATAL: While performing build: conveyor failed to get: while converting reference: pinging container registry registry-1.docker.io: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-11-02T02:59:00+06:00 is after 2023-10-21T23:59:59Z
```

I checked my time. It is set to

```
          Local time: বৃহঃ 2023-11-02 03:33:09 +06
           Universal time: বুধ 2023-11-01 21:33:09 UTC
                 RTC time: বুধ 2023-11-01 21:33:09
                Time zone: Asia/Dhaka (+06, +0600)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: ac
```

Why is it happening? Is it related to apptainer or dockerhub.